# Delete values occurring between large percentage shifts

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a timeseries df comprised of daily Interest Rates points in column A ( IR aka Interest Rate) and the relative change from one day to the next in column B ( Rel Shift).

DF looks something like the below:

```
                   IR      Shift
May/30/2019        5.9%    1.67% 
May/29/2019        6%      1.69%      
**May/28/2019      5.9%   -292%**
May/27/2019        20.2%  -1.4%
May/26/2019        20.5%   2.5% 
**May/25/2019      20%     292%** 
May/24/2019        5.1%    -
```

My df shape is 4000x 2 and these large percentage changes are persistent throughout the df. In other words, the rates spike up, level off - and then at some point spike down again..or vice versa. So in the above IR changed 292%, leveled off  and then spiked down 292%

Goal is to convert values lying between spikes above >50% to np.nan, inclusive of the date the spike occurred -  effectively deleting those data points so that I can impute the them with more sensible data - in the 5%-6% range....

So the DF should look something like this:

```
                    IR      Shift
May/30/2019        5.9%    1.67% 
May/29/2019        6%      1.69%      
May/28/2019        np.nan
May/27/2019        np.nan
May/26/2019        np.nan
May/25/2019        np.nan    
May/24/2019        5.1%    -
```

This is what i have so far for the loop --

```
for i in df1:
    if df1['col_B'][i] > .50:
        df1['col_A'][i] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have some not cleared area also after the "clear range",
I extended your DataFrame by one row, so it contains:

```
           Day     IR  Shift
0  May/30/2019   5.9%  1.67%
1  May/29/2019     6%  1.69%
2  May/28/2019   5.9%  -292%
3  May/27/2019  20.2%  -1.4%
4  May/26/2019  20.5%   2.5%
5  May/25/2019    20%   292%
6  May/24/2019   5.1%     2%
7  May/23/2019   5.0%      -
```

And now how to solve the issue:

First define a function detecting start and end of the "clear range",
based on 2 auxiliary columns, which will be created soon:

```
def detect(row):
    if row.Shft1 < -50:
        detect.retVal = True
    elif row.Shft2 > 50:
        detect.retVal = False
    return detect.retVal
```

Then compute these 2 auxiliary columns:

```
df['Shft1'] = df.Shift.apply(lambda x: 0.0 if x == '-' else float(x.rstrip('%')))
df['Shft2'] = df.Shft1.shift(fill_value=0)
```

The actual computation involves the following code:

```
detect.retVal=False
df.IR.mask(df.apply(detect, axis=1), np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Reading of the above code start from `df.apply(detect, axis=1)`.
This instruction computes the mask, indicating rows where `IR` value
should be cleared (replaced with *NaN*).

Then move on to `mask` function itself. It is applied to `df.IR` column,
using just computed mask, thus clearing the indicated rows.

And the last step is to drop both auxiliary columns:

```
df.drop(columns=['Shft1', 'Shft2'], inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
           Day    IR  Shift
0  May/30/2019  5.9%  1.67%
1  May/29/2019    6%  1.69%
2  May/28/2019   NaN  -292%
3  May/27/2019   NaN  -1.4%
4  May/26/2019   NaN   2.5%
5  May/25/2019   NaN   292%
6  May/24/2019  5.1%     2%
7  May/23/2019  5.0%      -
```

Comment: Great thank you Vaildi. One thing, however. Seem to be getting an error when executing df.IR.mask(df.apply(detect, axis=1), np.nan, inplace=True). Error Indicating : df1.IR.mask(df1.apply(detect, axis=1), np.nan, inplace=True), pointing to the column name.....

Comment: ah, ok fixed it via df.['IR'].mask..but unfortunately it did not replace the values in between the large movements...

Comment: Also, I should add that none of the values are in '%' form. I mention this as i noticed that you used the rstrip function for %....not sure if is the reason for the code not working....

Comment: Probably it is enough to delete *rstrip('%')*. But note that one cell contains "-", so this column will still have *object* type (a mixture of strings and numbers). And as far as the error with *df.IR* is concerned, maybe you use some older version of *Pandas*, which does not allow *attribute access* to a column.

Comment: oh, sorry, the ''--'' was just for the sake of clarifying the issue at hand... the actual data does not contain any strings....

Comment: So it seems that *Shft1* column is not needed and you can use just *Shift* column instead (but do not drop it at the end).